# How to setup multiple Jenkins jobs to trigger after each other?

Tags: jenkins

I am working to setup CI for my NodeJS and Angular project. The manual process is to start the Node server first on cmd-A, and start the client (Angular) on different cmd-B. Then I launch the webdriver-manager to be able to test Angular Unit tests on cmd-C, and finally I execute the tests using `protractor`.

I am not sure how to implement this process in a Jenkins job. I am assuming I may have to define 4 different jobs.

1. JobA - `npm start` (for Node server)
2. JobB - `npm start` (for Angular code)
3. JobC - `webdriver-manager start`
4. JobD - `protractor tests.js`

I am not sure if the server is launched in JobA that means the build is still running, how can I send a trigger to JobB (once JobA has successfully started the server). How do I set up these 4 jobs?  What is the most optimized way in Jenkins for achieving this entire process?

### My folder structure is:

```
>Project Root
    >>server
    >>>tests
    >>>package.json
    >>client
    >>>comp1.ts
    >>>comp1.spec.js
    >>package.json
```

Note: Server side tests are available in `server/tests` folder. Client side test are available in `client/*.spec.js` files. Right now the goal is to run client tests, which as pre-requisite to start server, start client, start webdriver-manager plugin, and then run the tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pipeline of jobs based on upstream/downstram relationship. It's dificult show it here but I'll try.

In your first job JobA configuration add **"trigger/call builds on other projects"** and enter the name the following for **"Projects to build field"** as JobB.

It will does when your JobA finishes well JobB be executed automatically.

In your next job JobB configuration add "trigger/call builds on other projects" and enter the name the following for "Projects to build field" as JobC.

And your next JobC configuration add "trigger/call builds on other projects" and enter the name the following for "Projects to build field" as JobD.

Now you have a Build pipeline with all the jobs relations done. Then you can run the main job, in this case JobA and jenkins will follow the secuence and will execute all the jobs one after time following jobs sequence.

You should run all jobs task using a shell script and call it into the job adding a command line shell.

This is an example of the use the upstream/downstram relationship approach, that usually be use to build multiple projects in the same time.

You also can use [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) to visualize in a friendly manner the pipeline.

```
Latest Release: 1.5.4
Latest Release Date:Jul 27, 2016  
Required Core: 1.619
```

Keep in mind that all process that you run by a job, have to keep runnig as a service or standalone process, That not mean that the jobs keep running too. In the last Job, next to the proactor test ended you can stop your npm servers or kill the process related.

Comment: This is not working out for me. On my local, I open 4 cmd windows, 1-Runs node server, 2-Runs Angular code, 3-runs webdriver-manager, 4-run protractor tests. As Cmd 1,2,3 are independent this setup works fine. But in case of Jenkins pipeline JobA keeps running, and no trigger goes to JobB. Also, as JobA keeps running for very long, eventually jenkins Aborts it after few seconds.

Comment: try to raise your servers or process in a non interactive mode or background mode, I'm not expert in .bat script but you have to try doing a .bat script to call it into the job that run your servers into independent process to the jenkins jobs.

Comment: Ok, I tried this: Defined JobA, JobB and JobC as Upstream jobs of JobD. Then to kill Jobs A, B, C after completion of JobD I created a simple shell script called abort.sh and calling abort from Post-Build actions. But here is what's happening: I Build JobD. I expect Jobs A, B, C to start first. But only JobD starts. I don't understand why upstream and downstream concepts are behaving like this. Am I missing something? \n P.S. I just saw your comment above. Will try .bat script and raising the server in non interactive mode.

Comment: You also can try this. create a jobA, add 3 command line shell in the job, in each shell execute startnodeserver.sh (shell1), startangulat.sh (shell2), startwebdriver.sh (shell3) (all .sh run no interactive) respectively, add a trigger/call in the post-build acction to cal jobB;  create jobB in this job add a command line shell and call protractor.sh.  This is another workaround in 2 steps. If that goes well try to do the same idea with your 4 jobs if you need